# Spark NotSerializableException when overriding log4j logs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j, databricks

I have overriden databricks log4j logs using init script. When my code is trigged it is running fine till some point. when it reaches the below line:

```scala
val ds = df.as[MySDMData]

ds.map(a => func1(a)).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("header","true").save(s"${Interimpath}/sdm_outer_java")
```

it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: Job aborted due to stage failure.
Caused by: NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.log4j.Logger, value: org.apache.log4j.Logger@33280b3f)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: logger, type: class org.apache.log4j.Logger)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@78706dad)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@259eefbe)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@58203e28)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw@621d2f16)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw@49da2284)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw@4f8ac0c9)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read, name: $iw, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read@3fc7ede0)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029$read, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364029.$read)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@375936db)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@750dbdc3)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@4c9f0247)
    - field (class: $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $linef43f9ceebbd54e07ba09b7bf5984364041.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@e81047)
    - element of array (index: 4)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 7)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function2.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.$anonfun$doExecute$4$adapted:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodeAndComment;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetric;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$6664/133918073, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$6664/133918073@36b47765)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function3.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted:(Lscala/Function2;Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$6661/1112983908, org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$6661/1112983908@63563080)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, name: f, type: interface scala.Function3)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[4613] at execute at DeltaInvariantCheckerExec.scala:85)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (MapPartitionsRDD[4613] at execute at DeltaInvariantCheckerExec.scala:85,org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$$Lambda$7277/44213980@6853ff1b))
```

This is my case class

```
case class MyData(var case_id: String,
                  var mbr_facet_id: String,
                  var mbr_id: String,
                  ....
                  var tpc_chg: String,
                  var icue_evi_flg: String)
```

I am mapping my case class with other dataframe. As shown below

```
val ds = df.as[MyData]

ds.map(a => func1(a)).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").parquet(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_cpm_interim3")
```

when it comes to this point I am getting this error.

Is this error because of map function. How do I solve this?

**New Edit**

we have a dataframe df, and MySDMData is a case class having some parameters.

Using this I am making data type to same in both.

`val ds = df.as[MySDMData]`

here ds is a dataset

then doing below

`ds.map(a => func1(a)).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save(s"${Interimpath}/sdm_outer_java")`

where func1 is method accepecting dataset(ds) as parameter doing some logical operation and returning

```
 def func1(ds: MySDMData): MySDMData = {
            
        /*logical operation*/
 
  val obj = MySDMData(ds.case_id,ds.mbr_facet_id,ds.mbr_id,....)
    obj //return
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding an instance of `org.apache.log4j.Logger` to one of your class/case classes? see the below lines in your stacktrace:

```
Caused by: NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger // this type is un-serializable
----
field (class: ..., name: logger, type: class org.apache.log4j.Logger)
                           ^                                   ^
```

It is trying to serialize the logger, if so, **don't do that**, logger is not something to serialize and send it somewhere else, loggers belong to a specific scope of your code (they are meant to be specific only to where they're used).

Comment: And what I mean in the end, is that the best, and the only solution is to not to do so :D

Comment: @AmiMal, Please check the question I have Updated. But then how to use import org.apache.log4j.Logger in our Scala code? how to implement logging if I will remove

I are not able to understand how logger is getting serializable ?

Comment: @venkat What is func1? does it log something? about logger you asked, logger should be extended/implemented or whatever, exactly where you want to log something. if func1 logs something, spark tries to serialize tasks you do in map function, so it also has to serialize logger, and that's where it fails

Comment: Added more information in question. I am logging(Like INFO,ERROR..) anything in func1. How can i serialize a task in map function. please suggest.

Comment: @venkat Ok so you're actually logging. Let's take it step by step. First off, you cannot serialize your logger. Second thing, I assume that you REALLY need to log the things you want. 3rd thing, you need to see the logs somewhere right? when you log something, the bytes of that thing go to an OutputStream (your console for instance), even if you were able to serialize the logger, when spark distributes your tasks, you couldn't see your logs since you don't have a single output stream. these are the problems, I'll discuss about the answers in the next comment.

Comment: I am initializing logger like  this             
val logger = Logger.getLogger("SDMmodule"). SDMmodule is class name. please suggest.
for your question yes i am logging, and need to log the things. I am using Databricks

Comment: So what can you do afterwards? knowing that you should log your data in a single output stream, you should aggregate your log data, and after reducing the data into your spark master, do the loggings (this approach is not good AT ALL), but that's one approach. another one is to use printing instead of logging, get the log message from your logger and print it (this is also not good at all), and not sure if println could be serialized to. give it a try. At the end, my suggestion is try to avoid logging in this situation where tasks are distributed of you are able to

Comment: There are also other tools for monitoring spark, they also might help. and you wont probably need logging in that case. (search monitoring spark applications)

Comment: @venkat (this comment is not much related about your question), don't instantiate your logger inside your function. make a single instance in outer scope.

Comment: can we write this map function in any different way so that we don't  get into this issue. 
  ds.map(a => func1(a)).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save(s"${Interimpath}/sdm_outer_java")

Comment: @venkat you need to rewrite your `func1` function, there's nothing to do with map method. As I said earlier, if you really need to log, there's only one way: aggregate your logs: `case class MyData(<other_fields>, relatedLog: Option[String])` and then do all the logs after aggregation. it's better to use a monitoring library (search spark monitoring)