# Scala| Databricks - Monitoring logging - error in log analytics

Tags: scala, logging, databricks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am trying to create custom logging for my data brick notebook , for that I followed monitoring logging  which seems an only option for scala codes to have logging in databricks. I followed the steps created the maven project built the jars copied them to dbfs . Now i can see the log analytics workspace created is showing below error. why ? and also What i have to do to print the customs logs only in my log analytics for scala codes ? from cluster . As when

I am initializing logger like this val logger = Logger.getLogger("SDMmodule")

I was caught into this issue : [Spark NotSerializableException when overriding log4j logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847138/spark-notserializableexception-when-overriding-log4j-logs/71851912#comment126964522_71848137)

Now if again i will initialize will i not get this issue? What snippet of code i have to add in my scala notebooks so that i don't end up to square one.

Hope you can help !! thank you

getting error in

[image: error coming in operation log analytics azure]

monitoring-logging repo :

https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring